# Running programs only if they are installed, and ignoring them otherwise

Tags: shell, posix, idioms

When writing shell scripts, is the an idiom or swift way to run a program *only* if it is installed, and if it is not, just let it be (or handle the error in some other way apart from installing it)?

More specifically, I have a lot of servers which I access over `ssh`, and whenever I get a new server, I simply copy all my rc-files to it. The .zshrc starts `tmux` unless it is already running. Some of the servers (not all) do not have `tmux` installed. I do not want to install it because of disk space limitations, I do not want to have different rc-files for different servers, and I do not want my rc-files to be interrupted when executing them.

I have seen solutions involving `apt-cache policy <package-name>`, so I guess I could use that and pipe it to something like `grep -e 'Installed: (none)'`, but that would assume that the server is running Debian or Ubuntu, which I can not do, and it would only work for packages that were installed with `apt`, not things I have installed in other ways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`command -v <command>`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/command.html) is the common (and POSIX) way to check if a command could be executed (is executable and on the `$PATH`).

E.g:

```
command -v tmux >/dev/null &&
  tmux a -t name
```

(`>/dev/null` since, if the command exists, its path will be printed to STDOUT.)

It could be nice to put it in a reusable function:

```
maybe() {
  ! command -v "${1}" >/dev/null ||
    "$@"
}
```

Then one could use:

```
maybe tmux a -t name
```

And if `tmux` is available then `tmux a -t name` will be run, otherwise it’ll be silently ignored.

Or, if you want some feedback when a command is not available:

```
maybe() {
  if command -v "${1}" >/dev/null
  then
    "$@"
  else
    printf 'Command "%s" not available, skipping\n' "${1}" >&2
  fi
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This might help-

1) Assuming tmux is available in PATH (as it must be executable)

```
isAvailable=$(type -P tmux)
if [[ -x $isAvailable ]]; then 

...
```

2) Verify file is present on a specific path (Copying all rc-files)

```
export FILEPATH="..."
if[[ -f $FILEPATH ]]; then
```

Comment: What does `-p` do? With `-P` it says "bad option".

Comment: Note that this answer is all Bash (which is not mentioned in the question).